# Foundation form validation not working after inserting through jquery

Tags: jquery, error-handling, zurb-foundation

I have let's say the following form

```
<form class="callback" data-abide="ajax">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">              
                     <input type="text" name="clientName" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="Nom complet">
                     <small class="error">Oublié de mettre votre nom? :)</small>
                </div>
              </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">              
                     <input type="text" name="clientEnterprise" required placeholder="Entreprise">
                     <small class="error">Nous faisons affaire avec les entreprises!</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">              
                     <input type="text" name="clientPhone" required pattern="[\+][1-9]" placeholder="Téléphone">
                     <small class="error">Le format requis est +199999999</small>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                     <input type="email" name="clientEmail" placeholder="Email">
                     <small class="error">Une adresse email valide est requise</small>
                </div>
             </div>

            <div class="row">           
                <button  type="submit" class="button expand">Obtenez un rappel dans les 24h</button >
            </div>
            </form>
```

The error validation is working in it perfectly well, but when I append the same code through jQuery, the validation stops working (bellow the jQuery code where the form is correctly placed instead of **The html code for the form here div**) I've checked the resulting html and everything seems in place.

```
$(document).on('open', '[data-reveal]', function () {
            var modal = $(this);
            console.log('modal will open');

            modal.append(*****The html code for the form here div*****);
        });
```

Comment: where is code for validation?

Comment: Using the type + data-abide should do the trick, please check http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html

Comment: try adding $('.validate').attr('data-abide', ''); before $(document).foundation();

this should do the trick

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't resolves the problem as it isn't calling for the error class under the inputs....

Answer (score 0):

I think i traced the root cause of this issue too (#6407). I had been experiencing this problem for a while since the 5.2 release and I went through all the updates to Abide JS since 5.1.2.
I found that the following change in: ([ba8c41f#diff-0fecfcb7f50be59e4f71ef75a2d8be41](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/ba8c41fa877715ae3de4e8ba4d36ce4a408b4dae#diff-0fecfcb7f50be59e4f71ef75a2d8be41))
breaks the form input errors in the modal.
I believe this is because the fields are marked as hidden because the modal is hidden, and since the new change does not validate hidden input fields, the errors don't pop up.

I have also modified the Fiddle stavros-zavrakas posted above, to use the live-validate option with a fast refresh rate.
https:// jsbin.com/weyizaniza/edit?html,js,output

If you click on a input field and then click out of it, or onto another in the first form, you will see that the error instantly pops ups. While in the modal form, the input fields do not show any errors because they are not being validated.

Now try this with 5.5.1 JS attached:
https://jsbin.com/momocecuti/edit?html,js,output